# Rewrite Landau's quantum mechanics textbook by Dirac notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

I am reading Landau's quantum mechanics textbook for interests. I try to rewrite it by Dirac notation but this is not as obvious as I thought. e.g. , eq(3.8) in Landau, defines the mean value of an operator:
\begin{equation}
\bar{f} = \int\Psi^*(q)(\hat{f}\Psi(q))\,dq
\end{equation}
In Dirac notation:
\begin{equation}
\bar{f} = \langle\Psi|\hat{f}|\Psi\rangle = \iint\Psi^*(q)f_{qq'}\Psi(q')\,dqdq'
\end{equation}
where $\Psi(q)=\mathinner{\langle q}|{\Psi\rangle}; f_{qq'} = \mathinner{\langle q|}\hat{f}\mathinner{|q'\rangle}$. I am wondering how to show the equivalence between these two formulas?

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is really helpful.  I am still wondering if there is rigorous proof of the relation $\langle x|\hat{Q}|\psi\rangle = \hat{Q}\langle x|\psi\rangle$.

Comment: it is typically taken as a definition for one or the other of the $Q$s, so it does not have or require a proof